# CORS issue with backend deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and frontend deployed on S3 or Amplify

Tags: express, amazon-s3, next.js, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a backend built with Express and Node.js using TypeScript. I'm using the cors package to enable cross-origin resource sharing. The backend is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and works correctly when I test it using Postman.

I also have a frontend built with Next.js and TypeScript. When I run the frontend locally, the API requests to the backend run correctly. However, when I deploy the frontend to an S3 bucket or Amplify, the API requests do not work.

I have tried setting the CORS headers on the backend to allow all origins, but this did not solve the issue. I have also tried using the withCredentials option in the frontend's Axios requests, but this did not work either.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

i try many hosted website to host frontend like onrender,vercel
and API didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.